# Зачем замаривают червячка?

Tags: фразеология

"Заморить червячка" — значит перекусить, съесть чего-то немного. А откуда пошло это выражение? Почему червячка и зачем его надо морить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

•   Согласно первой версии, среди русских крестьян распространено было поверье, что в органах пищеварения обитают черви (подразумевалось, что глисты). И чувство голода, по их мнению, вызывают именно глисты, поэтому нужно съесть некоторое количество еды, чтобы черви эти насытились, то есть заморились и больше не тревожили человека чувством голода.

•   Согласно второй версии, выражение "заморить червячка" пришло в русский язык из французского. Во французском языке есть фраза "Tuer le ver", которая переводится как "убить червя". В средние века был распространен способ выведения глистов (и других паразитов)из человеческого организма путем выпивания спиртного натощак.

http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/73716-zamorit-chervjachka-kakovo-proishozhdenie-frazeologizma.html».

В прошлом  и в начале нынешнего века он был известен и в несколько ином значении – «выпить натощак водки или вина»: «Отец Лаврентий, отвернувшись от собеседника, стал вместе с другими замаривать червячка путем двух рюмок под запал» (А. И. Еленский, «Огорчение»); «А как, Пал Егорович, насчет червячка заморить? – спрашивает Николай Стаматич, указывая глазами на водку» (Ал. П. Чехов, «Из детских лет А. П. Чехова»). Такое же значение было характерным и для различных перефразировок этого оборота: например, «винный червяк сосет за сердце кого-л.» – ‘кому-то очень хочется выпить спиртного’: «Сосет его за сердце винный червяк. За стакан водки руку бы на отсечение с радостью отдал». (А. Мельников-Печерский, «В лесах»). Поскольку рюмку вина или водки, выпитую натощак, обычно закусывали чем-либо, в языке русской классической литературы оба значения фразеологизма заморить червячка могли употребляться и в какой-то степени недифференцированно, как единое, синкретичное – ‘перекусить и выпить спиртного натощак’:  Значение ‘выпить натощак спиртного’ делает связь оборота «заморить червячка» с умерщвлением паразитов в кишечнике более правдоподобной.

Какое же из значений более раннее? В русском языке оборот встречается с XIX века; в это же время выражения с аналогичной мотивировкой появляются в польском (zalac robaka – ‘залить горе водкой или вином’, буквально – залить червячка) и чешском языке (otravit’ cerva – ‘поглощением алкоголя улучшить свое настроение и аппетит и заглушить угрызения совести’, буквально – ‘утопить червя’ и диалектное otravit’ chorbaka – ‘выпить с самого утра натощак что-нибудь спиртное’). В романских же языках аналогичный оборот распространен уже с раннего средневековья. Например, французское tuer le ver ‘выпить натощак рюмочку водки или вина’ (букв.: убить червя); аналогичные по конструкции и значению обороты есть в испанском и португальском языках. Французские историки языка уверенно связывают оборот tuer le ver со старинным народным поверьем, согласно которому от глистов можно избавиться, выпив натощак водки или белого вина. Скорее всего, и польский, и русский обороты – это заимствования из романской фразеологии, калька французского выражения tuer le ver. Однако позже в каждом из языков выражение приобрело и национальный колорит. Преобразованию значения способствовала  ассоциативно-метафорическая связь «червь» – «кишки», «желудок», которая в русском языке ощущается не только из-за внешнего подобия, но и благодаря созвучию разных по происхождению, но схожих по форме слов «червь» и «чрево», «черево» – ‘внутренности живота, живот, потроха, желудок’. А представления о кишках и желудке во фразеологии русского и многих других языков сопрягается, как правило, не с желанием выпить спиртного, а с чувством голода: ср. «кишки марш играют». Все это и обусловило своеобразное развитие фразеологизма «заморить червячка» в русском языке.

Answer (score 0):

Вот тут 
http://otvet.mail.ru/question/11784113
и тут
http://otvet.mail.ru/question/24763441
собственно, всё уже сказано, пересказывать, наверное, излишне :)